# How to merge the audio stream incoming from other system

Tags: ffmpeg

The ffmpeg is running on my RPi 3B, currently.
My RPi has USB H.264 CAM and USB audio converter and is sending live stream to YouTube with rtmp.

Some case, audio source is coming about 150m far from RPi.
So, I am searching the solution to get the audio stream from 150 meter away.

My idea to solve this situation as follow.
 - Use extra RPi to send audio stream to main RPi with rtp
 - ffmpeg in main RPi can send the live stream, merging main RPi video and
   audio stream from remote RPi

Is this right idea?

Comment: Yes, seems to be a good idea.

Comment: Can FFmpeg running on main RPi, receive rtp audio stream for audio source like local ALSA?